# Firebase storage: files always accessible via URL?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am building a small web app using Firebase.

There is the steps :

The User connect (Firebase authentication)

The user upload an image (Firebase storage)

The user can download or see his images

```
<img [src]="imageFromFirebase">
```

The url given by firebase looks like :

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<Your API>/o/userData_YOQioOsgzUP0B0fTAa6BVK5KOxo2%2Fimages%2F-L-w7THGfT6qmX9UhLsK3.png?alt=media&token=61f6edf9-188e-4177-9ee2-34635ebc5a4a
```

With this URL, I can display the image on the browser only if the user is conneted.

The real problem is that I copied this URL and past it in another web browser (without being authenticated)

And SURPRISE !! **this image is displayed** !

I don't understand why the image is displayed ?

It is normal ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getDownloadUrl()) for a file in Cloud Storage for Firebase, anyone who has the URL will be able to download its contents.  This is by design.  The URL is "unguessable", so only people who actually have the URL will be able to see the content.

If you don't want people to see that file, then don't share the URL.  If the URL is accidentally shared to others who shouldn't have access, you can revoke the token that allows everyone to see the content.

Comment: We are sur that the url is unguessable ?

Comment: If you would like to take a stab at guessing the URLs in my project, please let me know what you discover.  :-)

Comment: Can't you brute force this? The token is too long?

Comment: @siebmanb Sure, you can brute for it, if you have infinite time and money, and don't get shut down by Google infrastructure for suspicious behavior that looks like hacking.

Comment: How exactly do you revoke the token?

Comment: @JohnAndrews I believe there's a link in the Firebase console for each file.

Comment: But thats weird. If that link would be exposed anyone would access it. Why are there firebase storage rules then?

Comment: @JohnAndrews rules don't apply to download URLs.  They apply to access from the Firebase SDK, when you have auth information available.  If download URLs don't work for your case, then don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

As I know, the right way for storing then retrieving file is that you upload file to a path (folder/filename), store that path (a field in post for example) then when you want to show it, pass the stored path to the getDownloadURL function, it will return a full url that can be use as src attribute for img tag